# How to add the content of a certain number of rows just below the VLookup output (Google spreadsheet)?

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

For instance:

```
________A_____|__B__|__C__|
1 | Mouse     |  1  |  a  |
2 | Keyboard  |  2  |  e  |
3 | Headset   |  3  |  i  |
4 | HDD       |  4  |  o  |
```

=Arrayformula(VLOOKUP("Mouse",A1:C4,{2,3},FALSE) --would return "1" & "a".

Is there a way to make it return the content of 1 row below as well, that "2" & "e" along with "1" & "a"? i.e., the desired final output should look like :

```
________C_____|__D__|__E__|
1 |           |  1  |  a  |
2 |           |  2  |  e  |
```

Thanx!

Answer (score 2):

Try offset:

`=OFFSET(A1,MATCH("Mouse",A:A,0)-1,1,2,2)`

Offset in Google sheets is an arrayformula, so it can return multiple rows and columns.

Match function gives the number of row with matched name.

Comment: However, when i use it along with importrange (as below) it gives an error : "Argument must be a range". Is there any work around for that as well. Thank you. 

=OFFSET(IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheetkey","sheet!A1"),MATCH("Mouse",IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheetkey","sheet!A:A"),0)-1,1,2,2)